# Redirect with turbolinks from javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

Is it possible to make `window.location.replace` or `window.location.href` work with turbolinks like it's a simple  link?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From the documentation: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#triggering-a-turbolinks-visit-manually

> You can use `Turbolinks.visit(path)` to go to a URL through Turbolinks.
>
> You can also use `redirect_to path, turbolinks: true` (or `turbolinks: :advance`) in Rails to perform a redirect via Turbolinks.

---

This should work:

```
Turbolinks.visit('http://google.com')
```

Comment: This has changed to `redirect_to path, turbolinks: true`

Comment: @jthomas Not quite. You've provided `ruby` code, namely `rails` code. The original question was how to trigger `turbolinks` redirect/reload from `javascript`.

Comment: Sad it doesn't have callback.

Comment: @hlcs what do you mean? Do you want to execute some javascript code after the `Turbolinks.visit(...)` execution?

Comment: @MrYoshiji yeah I did this by binding on page:change and unbind inside function.

Comment: In Turbolinks 5 it's `turbolinks: :advance` again.

Comment: @hlcs [this is the list](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/blob/master/README.md#full-list-of-events) of supported callbacks

Answer (score 4):

In case you implement Turbo Hotwired the basic usage is

```js
Turbo.visit(your_url);
```

As decribed **[here](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/drive)**

other usage with a stimulus controller

```js
import { Controller } from 'stimulus';
import { visit } from '@hotwired/turbo';

export default class extends Controller {

    myEvent(event){
       // do some code
       // eg <span data-action="click->myController#myEvent" data-url="https://example.com/...">Hello</span> in case 
       // in case element is an button you don't need specify the event (default is click)

       this.goToUrl(event.currentTarget.dataset.url);
    }
  
    goToUrl(url){
       visit(url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

As written [here](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#triggering-a-turbolinks-visit-manually)

> You can use Turbolinks.visit(path) to go to a URL through Turbolinks.